# Babel-Node keeps trying to transform .stylus files

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have no idea why this is happening, but when either trying to use:

```
babel-node src/server.js
```

or

```
nodemon --exec babel-node --stage 0 --ignore='/node_modules/' --watch src/server.js -- src/server.js
```

I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: .../src/components/App/App.styl: Unexpected token (10:11)

9  | html
10 |   min-width: 767px; min-height: 100%; height: 100%;
```

It seems like it's because it's trying to transform a stylus file? But I have no idea why. The file is included in App.js as:

```
import styles from './App.styl';
```

I thought it would just ignore a file with a non .js/.jsx extension? When I use webpack it compiles server.js perfectly (I have stylus-loader) and I can node server.js from the output, so production side is fine, I was just hoping to run server.js directly with babel for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`babel-node` is just Node with the babel transpiler loaded for `.js`/`.jsx` files just like you said. That error is not coming from `babel-node`, it is coming from `node` itself, because that will become

```
var styles = require('./App.styl');
```

and node will just try to load it because you have told it to `require` a file and so it's doing just what you've told it.

Only webpack has been configured to know what to do with `.styl` files, not Node.